# Passing array argument to a function

Tags: c, argument-passing, function-parameter

On calling the function

```
int sum_array(int array[], int arr_length)
{ 
   int sum = 0;  
   while(--arr_length >= 0)
      sum += array[arr_length];
   return sum;
}
```

in main function

```
 int main()
{
    int b[10];
    ...
    total = sum_array(b,10);
    ...
}
```

why passing the argument `b` , not `b[]` as `sum_array(b[],10)`?
**NOTE**: I have no knowledge of pointers.

Comment: Because `b` is the name of the variable; the brackets are part of the type of the variable and not needed to call a function.

Comment: @RobI Should it(`b[]` be passed or not?

Comment: The variable `b` may be passed to the function as it is written - `sum_array(b,10)`.  There is no need (and it would not work) to pass `b[]` to the function.

Comment: yes.....thats my question why i can't pass `b[]`?

Comment: "why i can't pass b[]" -- `b[]` is a series of 3 tokens, not the sort of thing you can pass around. What you want to pass is the array `b`, and you do that by using its name, `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, arrays are passed as a *pointer* to the first element. The *type* of `b` is array.

When passing `b`, you're actually passing a pointer to  the first element of the array.

Comment: You **must** read a tutorial. Pointers are the very very basics.

Comment: I am only two chapter far from pointers. But what for now? any other way to understand this?

Comment: Try to write code with pointers, play with it.. it'll crash, you'll debug, you'll sweat but finally will understand.

Comment: "But what for now?" -- Um, read those two chapters and then the pointers chapter, *then* come to SO. The FAQ says that doing it the other way around is improper.

Comment: @haccks Nothing is impossible.. "*a journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step*".

Comment: @MarounMaroun; "The type of `b` is array" then `int` stands for what?

Comment: @haccks When you write `int b;` then `b` is a variable of type *int* (integer). But when you write `int b[10];` then `b` is *array* of 10 integers.

Comment: @MarounMaroun; Does `int b[10]` means b is a variable of array type which having elements of integer type?

Comment: @haccks [This link](http://www.mycplus.com/tutorials/c-programming-tutorials/arrays/) should help you better understanding arrays.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32524/discussion-between-maroun-maroun-and-haccks)

Answer (score 1):

- why passing the parameter b and not b[] as sum_array(b[],10)

*Short answer:* Because `b[]` is invalid syntax.

Here

```
int b[10];
```

variable `b` is declared. `int [10]` is type of variable.

Since functions accept identifiers as parameters, not types, you should pass identifier to function. Identifier is `b`.

- NOTE: I have no knowledge of pointers.

It has nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The function is expecting a pointer to an int array, so you need to pass a pointer to the start of the array. `b[10]` points to the eleventh (!) index of a ten element array.